# Rtl-sdr on mac Os X

Tags: macos, usb, drivers, radio, libusb

I'm trying to use my R820T2 dongle as a SDR receiver on my Mac. (to receive ADS-B signals). I've followed the installation as discribed here: http://www.hfunderground.com/wiki/RTL-SDR. When I try to run rtl_test however, it gives me this:

Found 1 device(s):
  0:  ezcap USB 2.0 DVB-T/DAB/FM dongle

Using device 0: ezcap USB 2.0 DVB-T/DAB/FM dongle
**Failed to open rtlsdr device #0.**

Does anyone know how to fix this?

I've seen how this can be fixed on Linux, by adding some rules in udev, but this is of course not possible in OS X

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and solved installing rtl-sdr using **brew**

```
brew install rtl-sdr
```

Have a nice day!

Comment: Homebrew is a packet manager for OS X http://brew.sh